# Working with a Limited Budget: Website Builders vs Custom Build vs Something Else

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, squarespace

I am a designer/developer with both Drupal and Wordpress experience. I am currently working on a project with a very limited budget. The requirements of the project are relatively simple (a few basically static pages, contact form, etc) but I need to spend significant time on UX (user interviews, usability testing, etc) and do not have time for much custom theming.

I am leaning towards using Squarespace or purchasing a WordPress theme but I am concerned about limitations/the time customizations will take with both. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you.

Paul

Comment: Is there scope for the site to evolve into something more than just static pages in the future? That's where I'd choose Wordpress, if not, go with Squarespace / Wix you don't have the hassle of updating plugins / CMS and hosting is much simpler to manage

Comment: Thank you Daniel!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm actually assisting on a similar project, it's just a basic HTML template that's been re-skinned and for the little dynamic functionality that's required, we've used PHP. That's always another option if you want a little more control